# Magento 2 backoffice - crash category page

Tags: magento2, category

I have never worked for the moment on a magento 2 project and I decided to do some testing on my side.

My configuration : Ubuntu 18.04 - Apache/2.4.29 - PHP 7.2.13 - Magento 2.3.0

I had no problem installing Magento.

I did a little tour on the bakoffice and I went directly to the Magento 2 migration tool.

And I started by migrating only the configuration:
bin/magento migrate:settings [-r|--reset] {}

Then I went back to the backoffice and realized that the category page was not showing, there is an error in the browser "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".
I do not know if the problem has always existed.

I deleted all the cache of magento & the logs magento & logs apache.
I activated the developer mode : bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
And I reloaded the category page.

The only log generated is debug.log of magento :

```
[2018-12-21 13:22:43] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://test.fr/admin_769ieh/catalog/category/index/key/6ecb4c1e1d0cd32447389cc81fd12fe6432ed6f807dc2941f5ddcee76c6b4295/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
```

This is the only page of the backoffice that crashes ...

I do not know where to look for someone can help me :-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look in the `core_config_data` table in the db, and check the settings for: 
`web/unsecure/base_url` , `web/secure/base_url`,  and `web/cookie/cookie_domain`. If you're not using SSL those first two values should be the same. The cookie domain should be `localhost` or whatever domain you're using, so that cookies work properly.

Comment: For this test version I do not use ssl certificate. 
I did not specify but I use magento in multi store, I made apache vitualhost with subdomains (1.test.fr; 2.test.fr, 3.test.fr). 
And for all three in store, I configured web/unsecure/base_url &  web/secure/base_url. And for web/cookie/cookie_domain,  I configured for store 1 -> 1.test.fr; store 2 -> 2.test.fr; store 3 -> 3.test.fr.
Is it correct? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I would try clearing your cookies and trying again. You can also try setting all sites to use cookie `.test.fr` (omit the number but include the dot). Also check the `cookie_path` setting in the db as well.

Comment: I configured all cookies as you suggested (.test.fr) and for cookie_path I indicate the root (/) by default. I emptied all the caches and indexes of magento and the cache of my browser. But it does not work, I do not know what to do :-(